# hardware for exporting timecode to camera

Tags: usb, bluetooth, pcie, usb-c

I have cubase pro generating timecode (TC), which I want to export to a camera with DIN connection (eg., Canon R5C).

What would you recommend if such thing exists for 3m to 5m distance beween PC and camera ? (eg., usb to DIN ?)

Are wireless solutions acceptable latency wise ?

Can I use the existing motherboard's sound card to export TC (free run) ?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I'm struggling to see the use-case for this. Why would Cubase be a good master TC generator? It doesn't use RTC. The camera is going to be generating 'absolute' time code, based on the clock set inside it. Cubase doesn't give a @£$% about absolute TC. If you're trying to sync something like a music video, then you can just record the camera's internal mic of whatever playback speaker you're using to picture & get DaVinci/FCP etc to auto-sync afterwards for a multi-cam setup.

Comment: @Tetsujin Off topic. Cubase has builtin timecode for sound tracks and videos.

Comment: AFAIK Canon R5C have internal timecode module, why do not use it?